# Weapon for scorpion hunting?

Tags: pest-control

I'm a new homeowner, and I purchased in a low-price area in East Mesa, Arizona. It is a great house and I got a great deal, but I discovered some scorpions outside the house (see photo) while I was washing the siding. This is to be expected, after all we are in the desert, and they were here before me and will be here long after I'm gone. We can't do anything to eliminate them completely, and I accept that. I want to reduce the possibility of getting stung though, and mostly that means keeping them out of the house. I have addressed the issue with standard pest control and I'll be working on sealing the house over time.

However, a popular way to deal with the issue out here, is to simply go out at night with a black light, hunting the scorpions down and killing them, in person, if you will. I would like to make this fun, and I'm a little nervous about the common method of just stepping on them. So, I want to purchase or design some kind of weapon that will kill them from a short distance away. I'm a gun enthusiast so I would love said weapon to resemble a rifle, in usage anyway - I don't care what it looks like.

The popular product *"Bug-A-Salt" does not work* on scorpions, they are too mean and nasty. Nuclear weapons don't work on them. So, I need something with more power, like an air-soft shotgun or something like that. It needs to be relatively quiet so I can use it at night in my neighborhood, and needs to be safe to shoot at a downward angle into the ground.

Any ideas for some kind of "gun" to kill these suckers?

[image: Arizona Bark Scorpion found behind my house]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying an appropriate weapon to use.

Comment: I would not use a NERF gun.

Comment: Or maybe I would and you might have to hit it 20-30 times to get a kill.  That sounds like more fun.

Comment: A steel tamper would crush them wonderfully, although it might be a bit heavy to carry, at least it stands up on its own. You might want to add some UV wrap to the handle so that you can find it in the dark.

Comment: So, suggest a better place for it then. Rather than, you know, just complaining. This is a question about pest control for homeowners. It is quite specific but an answer would interest every citizen of Arizona. We all deal with this. It's a HOME IMPROVEMENT problem.

Comment: Have you tried asking the county extension office or anyone else located in your area who knows your particular wildlife? They're MUCH more likely to be able to give you a proven answer (or multiple proven answers) than we are.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making the extermination process entertaining -- and about killing off a wider population than may actually be necessary, or even practical -- rather than about home improvement per se.

Comment: Sounds like a hunting question? Ask on sports.se?

Comment: Killing off all the population you can find is the generally accepted method. There's no management of this species. I really hate the way people are so technical about what's the topic around here. This is a damn interesting question and you just don't want to help. So don't waste your time putting it down either. Asking for pest control methods is all the rage on this site, I just have a caveat. That isn't eggregious enough to make the question off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the home improvement answer was already provided - tamper would do a dandy job. You're looking for something that ain't home improvement, at all.

[image: Tamper, image from home depot website]

Comment: Tend to agree. Once you start talking about trying to add a recreational element, you're out of scope for this discussion.

Comment: Pest control is one of the most popular topics on this site. It's definitely home improvement.

Comment: I will accept this answer, but this isn't an ideal weapon given that these suckers can climb walls and are often found on the underside of objects in the yard. A gun fired from above might not always work either. Anything powerful enough to shoot the little suckers would also damage the siding on the house.